# Global privileges on the Stack Exchange account

Tags: feature-request, reputation, stack-exchange, user-accounts, privileges

I think some privileges should be global to the Stack Exchange account.

I have been somewhat active on Stack Overflow for a long time, and have a little bit of reputation. I discovered not so long ago other Stack Exchange websites and the global account linking them. The thing is, I have less than 10 rep on most of them, because I didn't have the occasion of being active enough on them.

But I know Stack Overflow well now, and the global principles of Stack Exchange. So I was surprised and very frustrated noticing I couldn't do really basic things like upvoting a question on for example the Gamedev SE, just because on this particular board I wasn't active.

Shouldn't there be some privileges that are global? Or a way to unlock some basic privileges globally when you have a minimum rep on at least one of the sites?

Comment: As soon as you reach 200 on one of the accounts, you will get a +100 association bonus on all of them. Just 4 upvotes on answers for [main] ;)

Comment: Oh. Well that seems to be a very good alternative to my proposition. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Shouldn't there be some privileges that are global?

No, because reputation is how much the community trusts you. On a new site, with a new community, you need new reputation.

> Or a way to unlock some basic privileges globally when you have a minimum rep on at least one of the sites?

You can. Once you reach 200 reputation on *any* site, you will receive a +100 reputation bonus on all other sites.